# How to create alias for dynamic fields in elasticsearch dynamic templates?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am using elasticsearch 1.0.2 and using a sample dynamic template in my index. Is there anyway we can derive the field index name from a part of dynamic field Name

This is my template

```
{"dynamic_templates":[
  "dyn_string_fields": {
    "match": "dyn_string_*",
    "match_mapping_type": "string",
    "mapping": {
      "type": "string",
      "index" : "analyzed",
      "index_name": "{name}"
    }
  }
}]}
```

The dynamic templates work and I am able to add fields. Our goal is to add fields with the "dyn_string_" prefix but while searching it should be just the fieldname without the "dyn_string_" prefix. I tested using match_mapping_type to add fields but this will allow any field to be added. Does someone have any suggestions?

I looked at Elasticsearch API and they have a transform feature in 1.3 which allows to modify the document before insertion.(unfortunately I will not be able to upgrade to that version.)

Answer (score 2):

In single template several aliases can be set. For quick example please have a look at this dummy example:

```
    curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/test_template -d '
{
    "template" : "test_*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 4
    },
    "aliases" : {
        "name_for_alias" : {}
    },
    "mappings" : {
         "type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "include_in_all" : false
          },
          "test_user_id" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "include_in_all" : false
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
'
```

There "name_for_alias" is you simple alias. As parameter there can be defined preset filters if you want use alias for filtering data.

More information can be found here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html